# How to filter Datagrid using DateTime Picker?

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datagrid, datepicker

I have two columns in Datagridview containing date & time stamp and status(string) which is from sql db updating in periodic interval.

I want to filter the data in datagridview by datepicker in VB.net.

Can any one help me how to do?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [DataView.RowFilter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataview.rowfilter(v=vs.110).aspx) property. This allows you to filter data in your DataGridView, using [expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx).

```
' Set the data source.
MyDataGridView.DataSource = myDataTable

' Set the filter.
DirectCast(MyDataGridView.DataSource, DataTable).DefaultView.RowFilter = String.Format("DateColumn = '{0:yyyy-MM-dd}'", MyDateTimePicker.Value)
```